# window.open (filepath) -opening popupwindow in new tab in IE11. how to open popupwindow in the same tab on click of link

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have DOTx files in dotx folder in my project folder . on a web page, i have a link , if i click that link , small popupwindow with options on it as [open , save , saveAs ] should appear on the same tab,  so that user should have options to open/save  the dotx file .

to show popup we are using window.open(filepath); in FF it is opening as expected but in IE it is opening in new blank tab with that popupWindow .

How can i show the poupwindow which have [open , save , saveAs ] in the same page .

i tried

```
 window.open(letterPath, "_parent");
// replacing the current page with the new pop up link
window.open(letterPath, "_self");
// replacing the current page with the new pop up link
var myWindow = window.open(letterPath, "", "top=300,left=490,width=10,height=10");  
// it is opening the popupwindow with options [open , save , saveAs ] in the same page , but along with that one blank popup window is getting opend , which i dont want .
```

Comment: Please, format the code correctly.

Comment: i am new to stack overflow. if possible can you format for me

Comment: Only add 4 spaces at the beginning of each code line. Check the changes I have done.

Comment: its good to me.thank you

Comment: any idea on my issue.

Comment: No. We will wait until an expert will see it.